# SSDT in SQL Web on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-data-tools

I have just set up a SQL VM using SQL Server 2014 web edition. When I start up the VM and go through the apps, I can't see anywhere SQL Server Data Tools yet when I look at the features for SQL 2014, SSDT is list under web edition, and is also listed under 2016 when that gets released. My question is where do I get installed? I'm not a pro at setting things up, usually there are just ready for me to use because of how my work is, but now I'm in my own environment I at a loss as to what to do.

Could someone please provide me with some help. I'm a complete newbie at setting up my own and don't know if it is installed and I've missed or if I have to do something. I can see SSMS etc. but not SSDT.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you see Visual Studio 2013 anywhere? Probably "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe".

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Data Tools are installed along with Visual Studio 2012, 2013 or 2015RC. You can find the how to download and install information from https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the (very) late response but this is exactly what I was after and had missed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the official SSDT blog and download the latest official (non-preview/beta) release from one of the related articles:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/

You should be able to install a stand-alone copy of SSDT, but as Eric noted, it's also run through the VS Shell so could show up in Visual Studio if installed. You'll be able to create a new project for SQL Databases if it's installed.